# Networkx ValueError: None cannot be a node

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to implement a Barabasi-Albert model, but I get a ValueError "None cannot be a node" at network.add_edge(new_node,node). I tried to filter the list so that there won't be any None-elements but it didn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
  def ba_network(N, m, seed_net_size=4):
        # Generate initial small seed network (clique of seedsize nodes)
        network = nx.complete_graph(seed_net_size)
        
        for i in range(N):
            degrees = [value for (node, value) in network.degree()]
            sum_of_degrees = sum(degrees)
            degrees_prob = [float(value)/sum_of_degrees for (node, value) in network.degree()]
            chosen = np.random.choice(network, m, p=degrees_prob,replace=False)
            edges = []
            new_node = network.add_node(1)
            nodes = list(filter(lambda node: node is not None, chosen))
            for node in nodes:
                network.add_edge(new_node,node)
    
        return network
```

Comment: `network.add_node(1)` returns None

Comment: Thank you! But how can I access the node I've added?

Comment: Never mind, I understood it now

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `network.add_node(1)` returns None.
If you want to access the node just inserted, take a look at [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html)